# Get multiple columns from a function depending on outer group by

Tags: postgresql, functions, group-by

I have first a selection of `trip_id` (for a train or a bus e.g.) in a (sub-)Table A

```
trip_id

350
351
360
```

and want to use a self-written function which takes the used `trip_id` and gives back the a TABLE with `trip_id`, used roads (in form of a `road_id`) and the sequence `seq` of stops for this trip (here for example trip no. 350):

```
SELECT * FROM getroutepertrip(350)
-----
trip_id   road_id    seq

350       a1        1
350       g4        2
350       a2        3
 .        .         .
 .        .         .
 .        .         .
```

The desired oucome of the whole problem should be like this above but for all the trips from the CTE subselect. Unfortunately, my function only can take a single `trip_id`. My first and only attempt is of course wrong since a subquery can't contain multiple columns

```
WITH A AS (SELECT DISTINCT trip_id FROM stop_times)

SELECT trip_id,  (SELECT * FROM getroutepertrip(trip_id))
FROM A 
GROUP BY trip_id
ORDER by trip_id
```

Hopefully somebody can help me here, it feels like I'm mentally in a deadlock...

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a LATERAL join, by putting the the function in the FROM list.  If you just put the function in the from list after table "a", you don't need the LATERAL keyword, as joins to functions are automatically lateral.  If you wrap it in a dummy "select * from", then you do need the keyword:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT DISTINCT trip_id FROM stop_times)
SELECT route.*
FROM A CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM getroutepertrip(trip_id)) as route 
GROUP BY trip_id
ORDER by trip_id
```

or

```
WITH A AS (SELECT DISTINCT trip_id FROM stop_times)
SELECT route.*
FROM A, getroutepertrip(trip_id) as route 
GROUP BY trip_id
ORDER by trip_id
```

Comment: Yes, that was my second example, without the subquery.  I thought I should show how to do it with the subquery, in case he needs to refine it somehow.  True enough, he needs to either get rid of the group by, or add aggregates to the non-grouped by columns, or just remove them from the select list, but I don't which of those he wants.

Comment: Thanks already! Do you have any idea how to avoid the group by e.g.?